# Get actual value that failed an assertion

Tags: python, assert

Is there a way to get `assert` to show the actual value that failed the assertion on top of listing the line that failed? Is there a way of doing this in **pure Python**? I have seen in `C++` `gtest` where you see the `Actual` value right where the `Expected` value is shown.

Comment: The question asked here has nothing to do with a description that I add but the value that has been evaluated. I don't see how this question is considered a duplicate based on the supposed duplicates given.

Comment: The duplicates explain that you can customize the error message, and that that can be used to tell you about the value that failed the assertion. `assert foo == 42, f'{foo} is not 42'`